# Spectrogram 2D and 3D

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, spectrogram, matplotlib-3d

I've created 2D and 3D spectrogram with python scipy. The 2D spectrogram is fully correct, but 3D spectrogram looks wrong, it has additional color blue. What is wrong 3D spec?

Here is code for 2D spectrogram:

```
f, t, Sxx = signal.spectrogram(data, fs=5e9)

plt.pcolormesh(t, f, 10*np.log10(Sxx), cmap='plasma')
plt.show()
```

And then for generating 3D:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

ax.plot_surface(t[None,:], f[:,None], 10*np.log10(Sxx), cmap='plasma')
plt.show()
```

Here is what I get:

2D Spectrogram:

[image: 2D Spectrogram]

---

3D Spectrogram:

[image: 3D Spectrogram]

Comment: What is a 3D spectrogram? A spectrogram is a 2D heatmap usually, I'm not sure how you extend it to 3D dimensions?

Comment: I wanted to plot 2D heatmap into 3D projection, where the 'Sxx' is z axis, perpendicular to `t`, `f` is the value of 'heat'.

Comment: Hi Malum, nice plot, I don't see many issues..  There is 14 ms of stationary signal, your sampling frequency (fs) is 5GHz, so you have 2.5 GHz range in your spectrum, Y-axis is correct in both plots. It looks like the color range is slightly wider in the 3d plot, I would not worry about that, Maybe you can correct it using vmin and vmax properties of the 2d plot. The Z-axis is in Decibel, 10*log10(Sxx) and not Sxx. Sign is reversed, I can't see where the -100 offset is from. Very small amplitude ? dynamics is about 40 dB.

Comment: How to make the same color range, i.e. from yellow to red on both spectrograms? How to setup any vmin, vmax for 3D spectrogram?